# Thread within service dies for some reason*

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've posted about this project before, I'm trying to create a service, from a `Home` `Activity`, that constantly checks if the screen is locked or not (`ScreenLockService` is the `IntentService's` name). If so, it creates another service to "listen" (`Listener` is the `IntentService's` name) for sound. If not, it stops the existing `Listener` service if one is running.

So to do so, I've created a `Thread` within the `onHandleIntent` method of `SLS` that should always be checking if the screen is locked or not. Here is how that's implemented so far:

(Sorry for the wall of code, I'll try to make it look pretty)

```
Thread checkScreen = new Thread(
    new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Boolean lockInput = false;

            while(!Thread.interrupted()) {

                //The first time the screen becomes locked is special, it should start the whole process from there
                KeyguardManager firstKeyManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

                if (firstKeyManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
                    lockInput = true;
                }

                //If the screen has been locked for the first time:
                while(lockInput) {

                //Put a timer here do slow the app down and figure out what's going wrong
                    new Timer().schedule(
                        new TimerTask() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                //if the screen is locked start listener service else stop listener service (METHODS WITHIN THIS SERVICE HANDLE THIS)
                                KeyguardManager secondKeyManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

                                if (secondKeyManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
                                    startListener(); 
                                } 
                                else if (!secondKeyManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
                                    stopListener();
                                }
                            }
                        }, 10000 //10 seconds
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
);



//Might be relevant to the problem, if the thread dies I need it to start back up again.
//This is part of the onHandleIntent method, at the very bottom, and not inside the thread.
checkScreen.setName("checkScreen");
Log.d(TAG, "Starting SLS thread");
checkScreen.start();
checkScreenAlive = true;

while(checkScreenAlive){
    if(!checkScreen.isAlive()){
        Log.d(TAG, "Restarting check screen!");
        checkScreen.start();
    }
}
```

Now, I have `Log` messages all over the place so I can see what state the app is in (starting services, stopping services, checking the screen, listening, etc). When I debug it and lock the screen for the first time, nothing will be logged until 10 seconds later it spams `Listener Service already running` about 20 times then the service dies.

Maybe I don't fully understand how the timer works in java, but I have no clue why the service is dying. I probably don't even need to do this in a thread, or maybe not even use an `IntentService` and use a regular `Service` instead. I've read about the differences and I think what I have is right.

If I should post more code I can, don't hesitate to ask. I'm trying to make this as straightforward as possible, this is my first app and I'm still easily confused by some of this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `while(lockInput) {` which never gets set to false and will generate a lot of `Timer().schedule` events.

This `schedule` will be kicked after 10seconds which is where you are seeing the delay.

I would start by changing

```
while(lockInput) { 
...
}
```

to

```
if(lockInput) {
    lockInput = false; //Only want this called once per check

    //Put a timer here do slow the app down and figure out what's going wrong
    new Timer().schedule(
        new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                //if the screen is locked start listener service else stop listener service (METHODS WITHIN THIS SERVICE HANDLE THIS)
                KeyguardManager secondKeyManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

                if (secondKeyManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
                    startListener(); 
                } 
                else if (!secondKeyManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
                    stopListener();
                }
            }
        }, 100 //Fire of the check almost instantly
    );
}

Thread.sleep(10000); //So we are yeilding to the system, don't want an essential while(true) loop
```

Comment: That works so far! Very simple solution too, thank you. The `stopListener()` method won't be called, however because the `if(lockInput)` branch executes only if the screen is locked, however I can easily call the method in an `else` branch. Also I had to wrap a try/catch around `Thread.sleep(10000)` because of an interrupted exception. Thanks!